# Connect to FTP site using SFTP and download files

Tags: c#, ftp, sftp

I need to download all the files from a `FTP` site. But i need to connect `SFTP` to connect. I am unable to find examples/tutorials to download files from the `FTP` site using `SFTP` to connect.

Can someone please point me to a tutorial or provide some sample code to begin with ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tamir's [SharpSSH](http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/category/SharpSSH.aspx) library handles SFTP pretty well.  And there are plenty of examples, but the gist is:

```
Sftp sftp = new Sftp(sftpHost, sftpUser);
Console.WriteLine("success");

// assuming public/private key authentication here...
sftp.AddIdentityFile(privateKeyFileName, privateKeyFilePassPhrase);
sftp.Connect(sftpPort);
ArrayList files = sftp.GetFileList(".");                
foreach (string file in files)
{
Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", file);
}

sftp.Close();
```

Comment: I have downloaded the `SharpSSH` project. Now how can i locate the library and add it to my project ?

Comment: You use Visual Studio to either reference the binaries (.dll's) or you add a project to your solution for the SharpSSH source and compile it and use a project reference. Do you know how to reference libraries in Visual Studio in general?

Comment: `References --> Add references` is it ? Where can i find the `.dll` file of the `SharpSSH` project. Sorry, i am new to Visual studio and C#

Comment: If you downloaded the .dll's you use the `References -> Add Reference -> Browse` dialog.  If you donwloaded the source, you need to compile it first.  I keep libraries to which I have source in my main solution and use project references (you'll see `Project` in the `Add Reference` dialog.

Comment: I think it is easy if i download only the .dll file. But i am unable to find the link to download only the `.DLL` file. Can you help me find the correct link to download the .DLL file ?

Comment: I don't know if the compiled binaries are available or not.  Just download and build the source.