# Retrieve external html file and securely display in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file, security

I am working on an online publication subscription site. I developed it in ASP.NET MVC 1.

Basically, the user purchases a magazine or newspaper and the path to that publication becomes available to them. However, the catch 22 is, they are not allowed to see the filepath to the publication as this will be unsecured.

I've built a function that can retrieve the publication and download it without showing the filepath to the user but this is a problem because the publication is an HTML file that needs other files and folders in the same directory to view the magazine or newspaper.

I know you might say to download the entire directory folder, but this is unreasonable as it can be up to 200MB. I thought maybe retrieving the filepath and then redirecting to a page that will load the publication in an iframe but I think this will be a security risk as well as anyone with a bit of knowledge of browsers can view the source and get the filepath from there.

If anyone has a suggestion of a secure way to retrieve an html file and display it in the browser, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `filepath to the publication [..] will be unsecured.` no level of obscurity will get this undone. You can prevent mom and pop from giving the link to their neighbours, but anyone tech savy (basically anyone below 40 and some above) will get your magazine for free.

Comment: Thanks for your input but all these other online publication sites exist and they seem to be pulling it off so there has to be a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy! Store your secret urls in a database table, and reference them by ID instead.

Set up a new Controller action as follows:

```
public ContentResult ShowNewspaper(long Id) {
    var mySecretURL = db.SecretURLs.Where(k=>k.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault(); // Grab URL entry the database
    string htmlCode = "";
    if(mySecretURL != null) {
         WebClient client = new WebClient();
         htmlCode = client.DownloadString(mySecretURL.URL);
    }else{
         htmlCode = "Page not found!";
    }
    return Content(htmlCode,"text/html");
}
```

So now if you call:

```
mysite.com/Home/ShowNewspaper/5
```

This will load the HTML at the URL stored in the database for record 5

You could also go a step further and check to see whether or not this controller action was called from your site (as opposed to directly) by checking the Referrer.

Hope this helps...

Edit:
You could also store the "Authorised User ID" in the database record too, and check so that it is only accessible if the ID matches the currently logged in user ID, to prevent unauthorised access to this controller action and therefore the magazine... if not, redirect them to a login screen with

```
return Redirect("/MyLoginURL");
```

Comment: You sir, are a real God send! I am already saving the "secret urls" and user ID to a table in my database and also authorising before directing to the page. All I needed was the know-how to get the html and dump it to the browser and you have given it to me!

SN: If I could I'd buy you a beer.

Answer (score 0):

Connect via **SFTP** to the remote server(where all the publication files reside) through C#. *[This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10885633/connect-to-ftp-site-using-sftp-and-download-files) shows how to connect to SFTP and download the file through C#.Net]* and download the file to your end to a **random-number generated folder**. Now, you can serve the file to the end-user.

Comment: I think I have made an error in explaining though. When I said external it should actually be "an html file thats not part of the solution it just gets uploaded but resides in the project". So I would not have to retrieve it from a remote server as it sits on my server.